# php code In If Else Condition Not Working Properly

Tags: php

table name --  breaking_news
field name -- status

I have created a single page and passes id from link click.

**Now I check if status not empty and status equal to Inactive** 
**then update status = Active Else update status Inactive**

**but it is not working properly.**

**It Only Works For If Condition.**

**The ELSE Condition of Code is Not Working . plz suggest me how to write in if else properly...**

```
<td><a href="activate_status.php?status_active=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><img src="img/active.png" width="24" height="24"  border="0" title="Active" /></a></td>

     <?php        
    $Admin = new admins;
    $sql = "SELECT status FROM breaking_news WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['status_active']);
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    if(!empty($row) && $row['status']=='Inactive') 
    { 
        mysql_query("Update breaking_news SET status='Active' WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['status_active']));
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Status Activated Successfully";
        header("Location:breaking_news.php");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {       
        mysql_query("Update breaking_news SET status='Inactive' WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['status_inactive'])); 
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Status De-Activated Successfully";
        header("Location:breaking_news.php");
        exit;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what is output of print_r($row)?

Comment: from the doc - `Returns an associative array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows` so your `if` should be `if($row !== false && $row['sstatus'] == 'Inactive')`

Comment: $row is getting active if status is active in database else status is inactive in database then it get Inactive

Comment: you should not be using `header` after `<td><a href=....` there should be no output before `header`

Comment: @folibis `empty(false)` will return true however [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code 
    ">

```
 <?php        
$Admin = new admins;
$sql = "SELECT status FROM breaking_news WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['status_active']);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if(!$row && $row['status']=='Inactive') 
{ 
    mysql_query("Update breaking_news SET status='Active' WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['status_active']));
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Status Activated Successfully";
    header("Location:breaking_news.php");
    exit;
}
else
{       
    mysql_query("Update breaking_news SET status='Inactive' WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['status_inactive'])); 
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Status De-Activated Successfully";
    header("Location:breaking_news.php");
    exit;
}
?>
```

you have just to ask if $row was have more or not, be cause `mysql_fetch_assoc`return false if it's empty look to this manual : [mysql_fetch_assoc PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

you have just do not use `empty()`

Answer (score 0):

Or like that :

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($row['status']=='Inactive') 
    { 
        mysql_query("Update breaking_news SET status='Active' WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['status_active']));
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Status Activated Successfully";
        header("Location:breaking_news.php");
        exit;
    }
}
else
{       
        mysql_query("Update breaking_news SET status='Inactive' WHERE id=".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['status_inactive'])); 
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Status De-Activated Successfully";
        header("Location:breaking_news.php");
        exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not found a row, there is nothing to update...

You may wish to do something like this:

```
    <?php
    if (!empty($row)) {
        if ($row['status'] == 'Inactive') {
            //update to active
        }
        else if ($row['status'] == 'Active') {
            //update to inactive
        }
    }
```

also you've got a typo in the second call to $_GET array: $_GET['status_inactive']. You should be updating the same row but with different status value.

EDIT
@toto21 I don't have enough reputation to comment on your answers but no, your answer is wrong. As I mentioned at the top - if there is no row fetched then there is nothing in the db for you to update, so your else statement makes no sense.